# Why does my JSON response crash on forEach? With TypeError undefined

Tags: json, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, axios, typeerror

I set up a Cloud Firebase db and I am making a fetch request to it however when I try to iterate through the array in the returned object I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined` and I'm not sure why.. I saw some posts suggesting to JSON.parse the res however it didn't change the output..

```html
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Submissions = () => {
    const [state, setState] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get("/submissions")
            .then((res) => {
                setState({
                    submissions: res.data,
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });

        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, []);

    return (
        <div style={{ paddingTop: "3rem" }}>
            <h1>Submissions</h1>

            {state.submissions !== null &&
                state.submissions.forEach((element) => {
                    <p>{element.patientName}</p>;
                })}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Submissions;
```

If I return the following instead of iterating the array:

```
 <p>{JSON.stringify(state)}</p>
```

I do however get the dummy data response I expected:

```
{"submissions":[{"submissionId":"NxkofnOyiZSjpBa918it","patientName":"Bobby Hill","onsetDate":"2021-05-28T01:41:44.368Z","immuno":true,"highrisk":false,"symptoms":true,"collectionDate":"2021-05-28T01:41:44.368Z","createdAt":"2021-05-28T01:42:00.042Z"},{"submissionId":"PuyDsvIlNC5Mi1h5u7b5","patientName":"Theo","onsetDate":"2021-05-28T01:20:06.275Z","immuno":false,"highrisk":false,"symptoms":false,"collectionDate":"2021-05-28T01:20:06.275Z","createdAt":"2021-05-28T01:20:06.275Z"}]}
```

Comment: You can git rid of `state.submissions!==null` and replace `state.submissions.forEach` by `state.submissions?.map`. where `?` is called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) operator. `.forEach` doesn't return an array but you need to so that's why we use `.map`. Also prefix `return` before  `<p>{element.patientName}</p>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially `state.submissions` will be `undefined`, and `undefined !== null` is *true*, because they're not [strictly equal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality).

`state.submissions !== null` => `undefined !== null` => `true`

Because `state.submissions !== null` evaluates to true even when there's no data you end up trying to call `forEach` on `undefined`.

To remedy this you could either

- do a non-identity [equality comparison](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Equality): `state.submissions != null`, or
- simply test for [truthiness](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) via `{ state.submissions && ( ... )}`

---

You’re also setting state to an object that has its own submissions property in addition to the one in the API response.

So your data, which has a submissions property, is under your component state’s own submissions property.

Effectively: `setState( { submissions: { submissions: […] }}`

So you’d have to access `state.submissions.submissions` to get to the array.

Set the response directly instead: `setState(res.data)`

---

The next problem you'll run into is that nothing inside your forEach will render, because the function doesn't return anything. Change it to [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and return the markup on each iteration:

```
{state.submissions &&
  state.submissions.map((element) => {
    return <p>{element.patientName}</p>;
  })
}
```

---

If your environment supports (or polyfills) [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) you can simplify this even further by eliminating the conditional altogether, and while we're at it use the arrow function's [implicit return](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#function_body):

```
state.submissions?.map?.((element) => <p>{element.patientName}</p>)
```

Comment: I attempted to use state.submissions && to test for truthiness and that one also failed me which is perplexing

Comment: You’re also setting state to an object that has its own `submissions` property independent of the API response, so your data, which has a submissions property, is under your state’s submissions property. Effectively: `setState( { submissions: { submissions: […] }}. So you’d have to access state.submissions.submissions to get to the array. Set the response directly instead: `setState(res.data)` Answer updated.

Comment: I tried using map with a return and it finally worked!

```
{state.submissions &&
                state.submissions.map((element, i) => {
                    console.log(element);
                    return <Submission patient={element} />;
})}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Submissions = () => {
    const [submissions, setSubmissions] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
            .get("/submissions")
            .then((res) => {
                setSubmissions(res.data);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.error(err);
            });

        // eslint-disable-next-line
    }, []);

    return (
        <div style={{ paddingTop: "3rem" }}>
            <h1>Submissions</h1>

            {submissions.length &&
                submissions.forEach((element) => {
                    <p>{element.patientName}</p>;
                })}
        </div>
    );
};
```

**Edit**: I recommend the code above. I assumed you separated state between data and gave my answer upon this. The answer below is not applicable to your situation. Anyways, I am holding it in case of someone needs it.

The problem is that your render part is executed before the useEffect. So in the first render your state would be `{}`. You have to handle this case by making your state `[]` instead of `{}`.[`Object`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object) does not have [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: `setSubmissions(res.data)` will set the state to an object with a submissions property. If you want to go this route you'd want to change it to `setSubmissions(res.data.submissions);`